# Multitail : how can I see multiple logs in multiple square size windows

Tags: logging, tail

What are the command line options to use to render output in below format using [Multitail](http://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use to `-s n` to specify the number of columns.

In your case it would be:

```
multitail -s 4 f1 f2 f3 ... f21
```

Since multitail fills the columns evenly, this would result in what you asked.

In case you wanted a different number of cells in each column, you should specify than using `-sn x,y,...,z`. E.g. to achieve what you asked for:

```
multitail -s 4 -s 5,5,5,6 f1 f2 f3 ... f21
```